# JS sort символы и цифры

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, имеется массив его нужно отсортировать в начале по длине, потом по первой цифре, знак равно должен идти после цифр, подскажите как поправить выражение чтобы равно после цифр оказывался. Так должно получиться

```
"1:ooo/1:uuu/2:sss/=:nnn/1:ii/2:aa/2:dd/2:ee/=:gg"
```

```js
// Исходный массив
const res = [
  '2:aa', '2:dd',
  '2:ee', '=:gg',
  '1:ii', '=:nnn',
  '1:ooo', '2:sss',
  '1:uuu'
]
// моя функция сортировки
res.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length || a[0] - b[0])
console.log(res)
// Так получается 
// =:nnn/1:ooo/1:uuu/2:sss/2:aa/2:dd/2:ee/=:gg/1:ii
```

Comment: Как вы думаете, что получится в результате вычитания `'=' - '2'`?

Comment: @Alexey Ten я в курсе, что второе условие не отрабатывает как надо, поэтому и вопрос задал, как его написать чтобы "=" в конец уходило

Comment: `res.sort((a,b)=>b.length-a.length||(a>b?1:-1))` ну нужно просто сравнить как строки. К вашему везению символ `=` в таблице ASCII идёт после цифр.

Comment: @Alexey Ten не додумался, спасибо!